# How do the big companies like mushroom networks/peplink get there solutions to bonded internet? Can I do that with a vps for @ Home?

Tags: networking, internet, bonding

I’ve been researching it for months. so far every method I tried: mlvpn, mlppp over pptp, IPsec over gre tunnels, and openvpn bonded lines have all failed, currently attempting a Golang solution for a channel bonding proxy. i need more suggestions if anyone has them thanks

Additional details: some of them have worked but not in the right capacity. i'm trying to bond 2x 150mbps lines which keeps resulting in slow speeds. my highest bonded speed was 70mbps.  the server can achieve 1gigbit after speedtests, so its not a server issue.

Comment: How (ie what OS/appliance/software), and over what distances are you doing the bonding?  On the remote side, are the endpoints on the same network, and can the connection feeding it handle the bonded lines?  Its definately possible to do this over OpenVPN bonded lines.

Comment: with openvpn that's how I got the 70mbps speed using Ubuntu on both sides, I couldn't figure out what it was. maybe it was my config? I tried all sorts of fixes and nothing. that was with client to server config. was I supposed to use site to site instead? the server is located in seattle I'm located in Canada, alberta which is pretty close to seattle. its just south west of me. The vps I used was from vultr.com which delivers quite a fast speed to their users and the ip's are on the same network.. thanks for the reply! :)

Comment: Did you try tuning the network stack   (Seattle - Alberta is apparently > 1000kms - certainly not a "LAN" type environment - See http://bradhedlund.com/2008/12/19/how-to-calculate-tcp-throughput-for-long-distance-links/ - although your distances are closer, I recon you are still running into stack tuning issues.   Also, see if multiple threads gives you better throughput - this might tell you something about tuning, packet loss and inter-site connectivity.

Comment: Thank you I appreciate your thoughts, it gives me something new to think about. Ill have to research some more

Answer (score 1):

In France OVH, one of europe's (probably world) biggest hosting company is offering this service. They give you an additional router that will open a VPN connection (using your ADSL, fibre, 3G, ... routers) to a "gateway server" using MultiPath TCP.

MultiPath TCP has to be supported by both the client and the server to work, that's why the gateway server is needed. The "official" router is limited to about 130 Mbit/s - because the router CPU is a 5 Watts 1 core Atom. It's a custom OpenWrt available on GitHub at https://github.com/ovh/overthebox-feeds so you can install it on more powerful hardware.